# kafka-connect-jdbc Teradata sink connector error

Tags: jdbc, teradata, apache-kafka-connect

I am testing the kafka-connect-jdbc sink connector for teradata. I am getting the below error while running the connector. Is the create table option is not supported by teradata jdbc driver?

```
[2018-06-12 10:55:54,172] INFO product:Teradata schema:null catalog: -- table:TEST_KAFKA_BULK is absent (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbMetadataQueries:60)
[2018-06-12 10:55:54,174] ERROR Task JDBCTDSinkBulk-0 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:449)
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.dialect.GenericDialect.getCreateQuery(GenericDialect.java:34)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.create(DbStructure.java:90)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.createOrAmendIfNecessary(DbStructure.java:63)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:78)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:66)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:69)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:429)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:250)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:179)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2018-06-12 10:55:54,177] ERROR Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:450)
[2018-06-12 10:55:54,177] ERROR Task JDBCTDSinkBulk-0 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:141)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:451)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:250)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:179)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2018-06-12 10:55:54,178] ERROR Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:142)
```

Comment: Can you increase logging on the Connect worker and from the DEBUG/TRACE logs get the actual SQL being executed against Teradata? And see if you can execute that manually without error?

Comment: I changed loglevel to TRACE but still its not printing the SQL generated. Also I tried running create table command with the same user in teradata and its getting executed.

Comment: @Sniper007 I am trying to import data into Kafka using Kafka connect on a windows system. Can you please guide how to go about it? So far I have downloaded and started kafka server  and zookeeper, written a producer in Java and consumed it with the consumer script which comes with kafka. How do I got about connecting Teradata to kafka using Kafka Connect?